# Why does the nodeJS 'Hello World' example not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

pasted a simple Hello World example from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_quick_guide.htm) to ubuntu machine. But it does not work. I get the output from console.log(), but navigate a webbrowser (firefox) to 127.0.0.1:8081 just outputs

> 'Problem landing page' The connection was reset
>   The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: It works just fine for me on my linux machine from Firefox.

Comment: Works for me as well. How did you run the script?

Comment: Does changing the port number help?

Comment: I think the error related to the firewall

Comment: I started the service in a console with `node main.js` Of course I tried several ports. I installed ubuntu (current stable version) in a virtual machine. I started the machine and the fist thing I did, was to run that script. I don't know if there are any default firewall settings